# How to create function buttons from variable items in a file Python Kivy APP

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am actually trying to create an application but I encountered a big issue

Specifically, it should check a folder filled with pictures for it's items and for each item it should create an ImageButton(already defined) in a Scollview GridLayout list. It works so far..

But when one of the displayed pictures is pressed, I want it to change the path of the picture on the main screen

**This is my Python code**

```
#This is outside the MDApp class
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):

#Inside the MDApp class
def item_choser(self, item) 
 .
 .
 .
  elif item == "car":
    
    #It first clears the grid layout        
      self.root.ids.pictures_grid.clear_widgets()
    

    #Then, the path folder of the items(pictures) is being defined              
      pictures = glob.glob(f"./images/items/cars/*.jpg")
     

    #For loop created to assign            
      for i in pictures:
            
         #This "z" is the number after path in format <path\02_test_golf7_tez.jpg>      
         #Different for every picture (01, 02, 03 etc)
         z = i[-21:-19]
          
         #Creating button with bind
         z = ImageButton(source=i, allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=True)
         z.bind(on_release=lambda x:self.chosen(i))  <<--- Here is my actual problem
         print(z)

         #Adding it into the grid
         self.root.ids.pictures_grid.add_widget(z)




def chosen(self, selectedCar):
    
    print(selectedCar)

    self.root.ids.main_image_display.source = selectedCar
```

**This is what the path folder contains:**

...cars\01_test_golf8_tez.jpg

...cars\02_test_golf7_tez.jpg

...cars\03_test_passat_te.jpg

...cars\04_test_crafter_t.jpg

All photos are rightly placed. For every " z " printed after the bind, it shows a different object in memory so until here everything is fine

---

**But here is where my problem starts.**

Let's say you want to pick the passat so you press the picture of it but somehow, whatever picture you press, the **chosen** function will always print "...cars\04_test_crafter_t.jpg"

**How could this code be made in order to bind 1 button to it's function?**

This was the closest answer found but either I don't understand how to use and integrate it in my code or it simply doesn't help [lambda x, i=i : i * x for i in range(len(pictures))] because it didn't work

Comment: You've hit a common issue with creating functions in loops, see [this explanation](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures).

Comment: This syntax is causing the error: `gala+z = ...`. Is `gala` supposed to be a collection?

Comment: @Mike67 - No, they are supposed to be variables on which I wanted to add distinct numbers at the end so they can be different in order for the bind to work.

Comment: @inclement Thank you for feedback. The URL you sent is actually helping, yet I didn't understand how it works so I wasn't able to implement it in my code (you can see in my last line from my main question)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the full answer, but I can't squeeze much code in a comment.

Make `gala` a list then append each picture to it:

```
gala = []
for i in pictures:
   z = i[-21:-19]
   tmp = ImageButton(source=i, allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=True)
   tmp.bind(on_release=lambda x, i=i:self.chosen(i))  # closure hack
   self.root.ids.pictures_grid.add_widget(tmp)
   gala.append(tmp)   # can reference later >  gala[0]
```

**Concerning the 'hack'**

The target function (lamda) does not run immediately. When defining the function, python uses **late binding**. With this, python stores the method address (lambda) and the parameter address (i). It does *not* store the value of the parameter. When the function is later called, the current (latest) value of the parameter variable is used.

Take this example. When `chosen` is called, `i` will equal 2 because that is the value of `i` when the loop is completed but before the function is actually called.

```
for i in range(3):  0-2
    tmp.bind(on_release=lambda i:self.chosen(i)) # address of i is stored, not value
```

The hack resolves this issue by forcing **early binding**. Using `i=i` tells python there is a default value for that parameter (like `def myfunc(i=5)`) and early binding should be used. With early binding, the (default) parameter values are stored when the method is created, resolving the loop issue.

```
for i in range(3):  0-2
    tmp.bind(on_release=lambda x, i=i:self.chosen(i)) # value of i is stored
```

The `x` parameter may not be needed. You can experiment to confirm.

@inclement provided a useful link in his comment: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Comment: I did not understand at first what you said but it make sense now. Still, after creating the list I printed it and indeed  it showed 4 different items in memory yet when pressing first picture, it still displayed the last one in the "chosen" function

Comment: I am still trying to understand how that "hack" works because for me it doesn't make sense... But that thing works! Thank you a lot for help!

Comment: Thank you very much, Mike! Exactly, I tried to understand the example from @inclement but I was not sure how to implement that in my code because it didn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the problem is in the ImageButton Class - you need to check there if exactly that button was pressed.

```
class ImageButton(Button):
    
    # ....          

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    """
    Check which of the buttons was pressed
    :param touch:
    :return:
    """
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        print(self.source)
        # You could then trigger an event from here and pass the Source/ID whatever as parameter
    else:
        # This Button wasn't pressed
        pass
```

You can check that with the `touch` parameter of the [on_touch_down](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/inputs.html) function. Check with which button collider the `touch.pos` collides. The `on_touch_down` event is triggered for all ImageButtons even when only one is pressed!

I always use the Button id to identify the button - and link that with more data.

Comment: Hello,

Interesting idea, yet I don't think it could work in my case because my ImageButton class is not part of the app so it doesn't know the self function 

Plus, the inheritance of my button is a little different: class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):